# Axes and title with Gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

Please i ask how can modify tamisage.data using 1:2 with another label ,
[image]

and how can i please change echantillon with échantillon ?
Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the script used to generate the graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the label, you need to use:

```
plot ... title "New title" ...
```

To add an accent, you could use a special encoding:

```
set term ... enhanced  #need to use a terminal which supports enhanced text
set encoding iso_8859_1
plot sin(x) w lines title '{\351}foo'  #{\351} is 'e' with an accent.
```

Comment: set term ... enhanced  #need to use a terminal which supports enhanced text Please can you explain me this phrase ?

Comment: i have {\351}foo in the figure

Comment: Please i have one more question, is it possible to set the axe's title below the figure or not?  thank you for help.

Comment: `...` is for you to fill in.  For example, `set term postscript enhanced`

Comment: @user1735757 -- You can put labels wherever you want `set label "foo" at screen .5,.5` will put a label in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Please i'm beginner with gnuplot, i have add set term postscript enhanced but i dont have the figure! have you an idea please?

Comment: @user1735757 -- to make a plot, I suppose you'd also need to tell gnuplot where to save the file.  `set output "foo.ps"`